# Errors in my PHP code while uploading the files on webserver

Tags: php

I receive multiple errors on different pages. The website runs fine on local server xampp but generates error on web server.

1. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        header('location:index.php');
    }

?>

<?php include'includes/header.php'; ?>

<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `about`");
?>
```

2. Fatal error: Call to undefined function php session_start() in 1

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        header('location:index.php');
    }

?>

<?php include'includes/header.php'; ?>
```

Comment: *'$query* see no var called $query in your code ... show us header.php

Comment: No, that is not the code which generates these errors

Comment: Have you got a closing `?>` in the `header.php`?

Comment: Why you have multiple <?php ?>, and I think in some script you forgot to close it. If possible use single php opening and closing tags.